# How to break L-shaped polygon into two polygons

Tags: python, polygon, computational-geometry

I have a polygon which is L shaped. How to break it into two polygons, prefereably rectangles. I use qgis, python, geopandas, shapely, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Based on your only example (which is probably not representative enough), I don't think a library will help you. You can proceed as follows:

- find the two reflex angles (>90°) to locate the piece to be removed;
- number them 0 and 1;
- create two polygons from the vertices 1-2-3-4 and 5-6-7-0.